# How to make a shot in spritekit?

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

I have created a method called `attackButton`. Inside this function, I wrote this way in order to fire a shot. `hero` below is a node where I want a shot to be born.

```
func attackButton() {

    shot.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: shot.frame)
    shot.position = CGPointMake(hero.position.x, hero.position.y)
    shot.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = shootingCategory
    shot.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory
    addChild(shot)

    let run = SKAction.moveByX(2, y: 0, duration: 1)
    shot.runAction(run)
}
```

The shot node is displayed on the scene, but the node never moves and after a button is pressed twice, an error occurs. I guess it is because of lack of code which is `removeFromSuperview()`, or `removeFromParent`, though I am unsure about that. So, why does the node not move to x direction? Should I write this inside the `update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)` method? Though to me this sound a bit too technical. This `attackButton` is detected by being written in the `touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)`by specifying the name of the node like this:

```
for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

            if node.name == "attackButton" {
                attackButton()
            }

        }
```

If I write this function in the `update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)`, how is the method is triggered? I can't figure out as the method does not know if I press the `attackButton`, because this `attackButton` is a node and the name of the node has to be specified, right? Maybe what I say does not make sense, but I appreciate if you understand me, and could you give me some code that enables firing a shot? Thanks!